# What is concept of left region of rindler space-time?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, reference-frames, acceleration

A accelerated object follow a hyperbolic path in a Minkowski spacetime diagram. Minkowski spacetime has two regions: left (I) and right (II) regions of Rindler spacetime, as it is shown in the picture below.

What is the concept of the left region of the Rindler diagram?

What is the concept of AntiRob shown in the picture?

[image]

Comment: MY NEMESIS APPEARS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the answer by Dale, you can choose many different coordinates in Minkowski spacetime (in fact, in any spacetime). While many presentations of Special Relativity focus only on Cartesian coordinates, choices of coordinates are arbitrary.

When dealing with accelerated observers, it tends to be convenient to employ coordinates "natural" to them. For example, it is convenient to pick the proper time of accelerated observers as one of the spacetime coordinates and pick a spatial coordinate that labels the hyperbolae described by those accelerated observers. This is the geometrical interpretation behind Rindler coordinates. In your diagram, $\chi$ labels the particular hyperbola one is considering, while $\eta$ measures proper time along that trajectory.

It turns out this choice of coordinates can't really cover the entirety of Minkowski spacetime, but only a wedge. Often, one employs these coordinates on the right Rindler wedge, which means we consider the observers that are accelerating toward the right of the diagram. However, nothing forbids us from considering the observers that are accelerating toward the left. A similar choice of coordinates will then cover the left Rindler wedge.

Hence, the difference between the right and left Rindler wedges is simply whether you are considering observers that are accelerating toward the left or right. Rindler coordinates can't cover both regions at the same time, so we often choose to work with the right Rindler wedge out of convention. Nothing forbids us from choosing the left wedge instead.

As for "AntiRob", this appears to be the diagram author's way of indicating that the hyperbola on the left is just a reflection of the hyperbola on the right. "AntiRob" is the observer "opposite" to Rob, in the sense that it is just Rob's reflection through the origin. Notice that Rob is at the bottom going up and right, while AntiRob is at the top going down and left. They are opposite trajectories. The reason to define AntiRob in this way probably depends on what the author of the diagram was discussing, so I can't give much more information without further context.

Answer (score 4):

Minkowski spacetime covers all four regions (I, II, F, and P).

The Rindler chart covers only region I. Note that coordinate charts are defined on open regions so the dashed lines on the left of region I are not part of the chart. The Rindler chart also does not cover region II.

Of course you are free to define a second Rindler chart to cover region II, but it would be a separate chart that is discontiguous with the region I chart. You are even free to have the time coordinate in the region II chart run backwards, just as you could in the rest of Minkowski spacetime. Doing so doesn’t provide any particular physical insight or concept, it is just weird coordinates.